# How can we know, that some method is applied?

Tags: java, methods, collections

Lets consider, that We create some collection let's say Map:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
map.put(10,20);
```

Now in example We have got "map" object and method "put" who added one pair  to our map. 
But the question, that torment me is how can I know, that method "put" is working and I will have new recording without code execution i.e. without run test.

Comment: You mean how can you know that `put` actually `put` the entry in your Map? I would count on it.

Comment: You can use the size method to check the new element has been added, not sure how you could do it without writing anymore code though.. You could debug it I suppose and have a breakpoint and check the HashMap in memory to see its contents.

Comment: Yes, this I would like to know. - Idos

Comment: **"without code execution"** - not at all. But if no exception is thrown, you can be pretty sure it succeeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look to [`Map::put()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)) API you will see:

> **Throws:**
>   `UnsupportedOperationException` - if the put operation is not supported by this map
>   `ClassCastException` - if the class of the specified key or value prevents it from being stored in this map
>   `NullPointerException` - if the specified key or value is null and this map does not permit null keys or values
>   `IllegalArgumentException` - if some property of the specified key or value prevents it from being stored in this map

and

> **Returns**
>   the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key, if the implementation supports null values.)

So using a `try-catch` and the returning value you can ensure the success of the `put` action.

---

But, if you want to be totally sure, you can override a Map implementation (in this case `HashMap`) and create your business logic.

In this case, use `put` and returning a `boolean` and not trowing any `Exception` (or handling them in the way you want).

```
public class MyHashMap<K, V> extends HashMap {
    @Override
    public Boolean put(Object key, Object value) {
        try {
            super.put(key, value);
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException | ClassCastException | NullPointerException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false; // or do what you want!
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And later **USE IT!**:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> myMap = new MyHashMap();

// printing result
System.out.println(myMap.put(10,20));   

// set result to a variable
boolean result = myMap.put(null,null);  // result = true

// or even setting and evaluating 
if (myMap.put(10,20)) {
   // success action
} else {
   // fail action
}
```

***NOTE:*** this is a java 8 implementation

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with standard Java functions, you can read their API. For example [map.put(K, V)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)). If something goes wrong an exception will be thrown - and you'll have to catch it and figure out what went wrong.